# Change render in my screen with boolean React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, react-native-ios

I want to change my render in the same page when i click on next button. In my component i have my state `next, setNext` initialize to false. The onPress to my button i change my state to true, but nothing happen when i click to the next button !
Here you can see the [Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEIQ7.png) to [Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy3wA.png) and understand more what i need ^^

```js
const [next, setNext] = useState(false);

{!next ? (
  //Step1 
  <BigButton
    title="Suivant"
    onPress={() => {
    setNext(true);
   }}
  />) : ( // Step2 )
}
```

And all my code here :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";

import BigButton from "../components/BigButton";
import BigTextInfos from "../components/BigTextInfos";

export default function SignUpScreen({ setToken }) {
 const [next, setNext] = useState(false);
 const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

 const toggleSwitchPassword = () => {
   setShowPassword((prev) => !prev);
 };


 return (
   <>
     {!next ? ( // STEP 1
       <View style={{ marginTop: 60 }}>
         <BigTextInfos title="S'inscrire" subtitle="Vous êtes :" />
         <View>
           <View>
             <TouchableHighlight
               style={[styles.input, styles.inputGender]}
               onPress={() => setGender("Mme")}
             >
               <Text style={[styles.darkGrey]}>Mme</Text>
             </TouchableHighlight>
             <TouchableHighlight
               style={[styles.input, styles.inputGender]}
               onPress={() => setGender("M.")}
             >
               <Text style={[styles.darkGrey]}>M.</Text>
             </TouchableHighlight>
           </View>
           <TextInput
             style={[styles.input]}
             placeholder="Prénom"
             placeholderTextColor={colors.darkgrey}
           />
           <TextInput
             style={[styles.input]}
             placeholder="Nom"
             placeholderTextColor={colors.darkgrey}
           />

           <BigButton
             title="Suivant"
             onPress={() => {
               setNext(true);
             }}
           />
         </View>
       </View>
     ) : ( // STEP 2
       <View style={{ marginTop: 60 }}>
         <BigTextInfos title="S'inscrire" subtitle="Finalisez l'inscription" />
         <View>
           <TextInput
             style={[styles.input]}
             placeholder="Email"
             placeholderTextColor={colors.darkgrey}
           />
           <View style={[styles.input]}>
             <TextInput
               style={{ width: 300 }}
               placeholder="Mot de passe"
               placeholderTextColor={colors.darkgrey}
               color={colors.dark}
               secureTextEntry={showPassword ? true : false}
             />

             {showPassword ? (
               <Feather
                 name="eye-off"
                 size={24}
                 color={colors.grey}
                 onPress={() => {
                   toggleSwitchPassword();
                 }}
               />
             ) : (
               <Feather
                 name="eye"
                 size={24}
                 color={colors.grey}
                 onPress={() => {
                   toggleSwitchPassword();
                 }}
               />
             )}
           </View>
           <BigButton
             title="S'inscrire"
             empty="false"
             onPress={async () => {
               console.log("s'inscrire");
               const userToken = "secret-token";
               setToken(userToken);
             }}
           />
         </View>
       </View>
     )}
   </>
 );
}
```

Comment: Your example isn't matching your description. You start asking if next is true while you initialize it as false thus meaning that the big button would never render. Your example should either ask if it is false or you should render the button after the colon.

Comment: Yes sorry,  it's `!next` and not `next` ! Thanks, but event with that, when i click on my btn, nothing happen :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit odd that its not working, try different approach - separate the return logic inside a function and call the function on render. It should look a bit like this

```
const [next,setNext] = useState(false)

const handleSteps = () => {
 if(next){
  return <BigButton
     title="Suivant"
     onPress={() => {
     setNext(true);
     }}/>
 }
 return <SmallButton /> //here goes the other component
}
```

and then call that handleSteps function inside your return

```
return(
{handleSteps()}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for help ! But that doesnt work :( so i think its not the way to render dynamic component only with state ... I think i will put all my code here ^^ maybe i miss something because React use the state for that too.. I really dont know  !!

Comment: i just give you more than little code.. I dont know if that can help you ! 
for exemple i "play" with the password for read or not the security parameter and only with a boolean that work !

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/vvoMJFekC Here is a basic example of how it works :)